# Can't open gnome-control-center: gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed cannot open display: :1

Tags: system-settings, gnome-control-center

when I used `gnome-control-center` it gave me a segfault error, so I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-control-center` but nothing changed.
After searching I tried `export CLUTTER_BACKEND=gdk GDK_BACKEND=wayland` and now when I try to open the settings with `gnome-control-center` it gives me the following error:

```
(gnome-control-center:16171): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 15:12:15.408: gtk_style_context_add_provider_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
(gnome-control-center:16171): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:12:15.409: cannot open display: :1
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it but I'll keep the question here,it may help someone eventually.
I ran this alias I have (feel free to copy it into your own .bashrc file) that basically updates everything:

```
#update everything
function update(){ # update and reboot/shutdown
        # apt
        sudo apt update -y
        sudo apt upgrade -y
        sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
        sudo apt autoremove -y
        sudo apt autoclean -y

        # apt-get
        sudo apt-get update -y
        sudo apt-get upgrade -y
        sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
        sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade -y
        sudo apt-get autoremove -y
        
        # fwupdmgr
        sudo fwupdmgr get-devices
        sudo fwupdmgr get-updates
        sudo fwupdmgr update
        
        ##update BetterDiscord
        sudo betterdiscordctl self-upgrade

        # snap
        sudo snap refresh

        # homebrew
        brew upgrade
        
        # reboot/shutdown
        sudo $1 now
}
```

So yeah, i just wrote `update reboot`on the terminal and it got fixed. One of this commands must have done it.